# Xamarin Forms Icon set in Content View

Tags: xamarin.forms

***How to set Icon and Title in xamarin.forms ContentView ?***

***Is it Possible in xaml?***

Comment: What did you try? Did you go through standard documentation like https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ContentView/

Comment: Yes I have seen but  I didn't get it